# order data on a plot by column not graphed in R

Tags: r, plot

I have this data set:

```
Store; 

  founder wt.Df Replicate Block Food_Source Viability
1       A4  5905         1     1     Regular 0.9523810
2       A4 24834         1     1     Regular 0.8095238
3       A4 24834         2     1     Regular 0.8571429
4       A4 27861         1     1     Regular 0.8095238
5       A4 27861         2     1     Regular 0.9230769
12      A3  5905         1     1     Regular 0.9473684
13      A3 24834         1     1     Regular 0.9047619
14      A3 27861         1     1     Regular 0.8571429

attach(Store);
plot(wt.Df, Viability);
```

My output:[image]

I want to order the Y axis by Store$founder with A3 on the left and A4 on the right. I finally want to connect by a line all come values in Store$wt.Df. my output should be A3 on left and A4 on right. 5905 for example should have a line connecting them.

Comment: Chad, I am no entirely clear what you mean. I think it might be more clear if you could provide some sort of diagram or picture of what your desired output is. I know you explained it above, but I did not follow.

Comment: I dont know about referencing stuff, but this is what I want but with my data:   http://openi.nlm.nih.gov/detailedresult.php?img=2936530_pgen.1001100.g004&req=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you're thinking of

```
library(ggplot2)
dat<-data.frame(obs=rep(c(1,2),each=2), type=rep(c("a","b"),2),y=c(1,2,3,4))
qplot(x=type, y=y, group=obs, data=dat, geom="line")+geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: how would you do this above example with my data just for 5905 and 27861?

Comment: use the subset command:

qplot(x=type, y=y, group=obs, data=subset(dat,type %in% c("a","b")), geom="line")+geom_point()

You can change accordingly to your data

Comment: Thanks JPC this is great. You really helped me out alot. Cheers chad

Comment: NP, my pleasure. Good luck!